# When passing scope in angular modal controller, it's not showing second time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am calling modal popup from my controller. It works fine for the first time but doesn't show the second time.
Here is the code for the show

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function (ev) {
    var scopeVar = $scope;
    console.log('$mdDialog');
    console.log($mdDialog);
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        scope: $scope,
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
    }).then(function (result) {

        //$scope = $scope.$parent;
        console.log($scope);
    });

};
```

Here is my hide function inside DialogController.

```
   $scope.hide = function () {
    console.log('hide called');
    $mdDialog.hide();
    console.log('hide completed');

};
```

Hide is executing successfully and followed by callback defined in show which prints the current scope.
If I remove scope : $scope and put transclude : true then it is not showing the data in dialog controller though you can show and hide it more than once.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the controller as a string? (i.e `controller: 'DialogController' )

Comment: Yup, didn't help @MohamedEl-Sayed, Had to workaround by re writing the controller code and setting transclude:true.

Comment: @satishsuthar where did you passed the transclude?

Comment: @VassilisPits instead of scope you can use transclude. this example is using another alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `preserveScope: true` to your modal options.  A dialogue removes its scope on closing by default.

Comment: You saved an hour.